Energy transfer in longitudinal waves
Consider a longitudinal wave where the particles of the medium oscillate. Let us assume two particles with approximately equal masses. If I disturb the first particle by applying a force ( F ), it will move from its equilibrium position and collide with the second particle. After the collision, a restoring force acts on the first particle, reducing its velocity from the initial value, $ v_{\text{initial}}$, to a final velocity, $ v_{\text{final}} $, which is less than the initial velocity.
Assuming the collision is elastic (ideal wave scenario), the second particle will gain the velocity $v_{\text{final}} $. The energy imparted to the first particle is $ \frac{1}{2} m v_{\text{initial}}^2 $, and the energy gained by the second particle is $ \frac{1}{2} m v_{\text{final}}^2 $. Since $_{\text{initial}} > v_{\text{final}} $, the energy transferred to the second particle is less than the energy put into the first particle. Over time, this leads to a reduction in the energy transferred. This means any ideal wave can't travel infinitely but a ideal wave travel infinitely. Please explain. and try to explain in simple language if possible. I will be thankful
